# Use predict function in mixed models to predict for new predictor values

Tags: r, predict, lme4, mixed-models

Here is my problem.

Sample data:

```
library(lme4)
library(ISLR)
data(Auto)

mdl<-lmer(mpg ~ horsepower + I(horsepower^2) + displacement + I(displacement^2) + (1|name) + (1|year),data=Auto)
```

I want to use this model to predict for a range of `horsepower` while keeping `displacement` at its mean value.

```
horsepower <- min(Auto$horsepower):max(Auto$horsepower)
displacement <- rep(mean(Auto$displacement),185)
data <- data.frame(horsepower,displacement)

# Use predict 
yVals <- predict(mdl, newdata = data)
```

`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'name' not found`

I think this error is happening because I am not specifying `name` which is my random effect inside the `predict` function. Does anyone know how to address this error.

In addition, I want to fit the quadratic function in the plot of `mpg ~ horsepower` based on the coefficients generated from the model.

Comment: Take a look at the `merTools` package, and the `predictInterval` function in particular.

Comment: For the error, take a look at the help page for `predict.merMod`.  It shows how to use `re.form = NA` to get the unconditional/level-0 predictions.